# Angular Default Value

Tags: angular

I have 2 questions.

1. I would like to set the default value of a dropdown to the first item in the array.
2. Once the item defaults to the first item in the array, I want to fire the (change) even to set the value of the second dropdown.

Problem:
Even if I remove the first option from the select, it still inserts a blank record. So, If I have `A`, `B`, `C` in my array and I loop through the array, the dropdown appears to have "" then the array. I would like `A` to be in the dropdown and then `A` be passed to the other dropdown from the change event.

I've tried having: selected disabled. That did not work. I can remove the first option but it still insert a blank value.

Angular Version: 11.2
Using Template forms.

Template:

```
<select name="agency" id="agency" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="query.agency" (change)="onAgencyChange()">
      <!-- I even removed the first option but then it just inserts a blank in the dropdown. -->
      <option  *ngIf="isTrueOrFalse" value=""  >Select Agency...</option> 
      <option *ngFor="let agency of agencies; let i = index" [value]="agency.agencyCode" >{{agency.agencyCode}} - {{agency.agencyName}}</option>
</select>
```

Class:

```
query: any = {};
 isTrueOrFalse: boolean = false; //This will be set when retrieving data.
```

Comment: Hi, please be more clear to this question, so that anybody can answer properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first question you can set `query` variable like this in `ngOnInit`:

```
this.query.agency = this.agencies[0].agencyCode;
```

And for second question you can call `onAgencyChange` after setting default value. So it's better to define a function to set default value and then call change methods `onAgencyChange`:

```
onAgencyChange(value) {
    console.log('changed call', value);
  }

 setDefault(){
    this.query.agency = this.agencies[0].agencyCode;
    this.onAgencyChange(this.query.agency);
  }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.setDefault();
  }
```

And for remove part you can use `filter` or `splice` based on your requirement. But don't forgot after remove function to call `setDefault` methods:

```
  removeFirstItem(){
    if(this.agencies.length >= 2){
     this.agencies = this.agencies.splice(1,this.agencies.length - 1);
     this.setDefault();
    }
  }
```

Here is working sample I wrote for you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-wgzktv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts